# What does 1[index] mean in c?

Tags: c, compilation

Why does the below code not generate an error and print the value stored in arr then followed by a junk value ?

```
int main() {
    int arr[1]={10};
    printf("%d %d\n",0[arr], 1[arr] );
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `0[arr], 1[arr]` same as `arr[0], arr[1]`, also `arr[1]` is UB.

Answer (score 2):

In C, `0[arr] == arr[0]`.

So,

```
0[arr]==arr[0]==10.
```

and

```
1[arr]==arr[1]==Junk value
```

Check this [SO question and it's  answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/381542/with-c-arrays-why-is-it-the-case-that-a5-5a).

> The C standard defines the [] operator as follows:
>
> a[b] == *(a + b)
>
> Therefore a[5] will evaluate to:
>
> *(a + 5) and 5[a] will evaluate to:
>
> *(5 + a) and from elementary school math we know those are equal. (Addition is commutative.)
>
> This is the direct artifact of arrays behaving as pointers, "a" is a
>   memory address. "a[5]" is the value that's 5 elements further from
>   "a". The address of this element is "a + 5". This is equal to offset
>   "a" from "5" elements at the beginning of the address space (5 + a).

Comment: Since you knew a duplicate question existed, next time just close it as a duplicate, instead of posting an identical answer.

Answer (score 0):

`1[arr]` is the same as `arr[1]`.

This is possible because `E1[E2]` is equivalent to `(*((E1) + (E2))` in C by definition of `[]` operator.

Note that if you declare:

```
int arr[1]={10};
```

There is only element in the array, `arr[0]` and there is no `arr[1]` element.